# Flutter: How to properly setup Pusher Beams when minimised or terminated?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, notifications, pusher

Im struggling with this topic a few weeks. I registered on firebase console, pusher beams, everything setup as is written in documentation, I copied example project from flutter [pusher_beams](https://pub.dev/packages/pusher_beams/example) package so that when i send notification and app is opened, alert pop up and when is minimised, notification is shown in notification tray.

Problems:

- When I tap on notification when app is minimised, i cannot check, which notification was tapped. I tried to add delay before that function but without help.
  PusherBeams.instance.getInitialMessage is returning null, when i break there, but debugger dont stop on that breakpoint when i tap on notification when app is minimised.
- I dont know how to handle notifications when app is killed. I found [flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service), but when i set isForegroundMode to true, unhideable (if that word exists) notification is in notification tray and when i set isForegroundMode to false, when app is killed, that service is killed too. Another possibility is to use workmanager, but that can be called the fastest every 15 mins.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();

    initPusherBeams();
  }

  initPusherBeams() async {
    // Let's see our current interests
    print(await PusherBeams.instance.getDeviceInterests());

    // This is not intented to use in web
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      await PusherBeams.instance
          .onInterestChanges((interests) => {
            print('Interests: $interests')});

      await PusherBeams.instance
          .onMessageReceivedInTheForeground(_onMessageReceivedInTheForeground);
    }
    await _checkForInitialMessage();
  }

  Future<void> _checkForInitialMessage() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    final initialMessage = await PusherBeams.instance.getInitialMessage();
    if (initialMessage != null) {
      _showAlert('Initial Message Is:', initialMessage.toString());
    }
  }

  void _onMessageReceivedInTheForeground(Map<Object?, Object?> data) {
    _showAlert(data["title"].toString(), data["body"].toString());
  }

  void _showAlert(String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
        title: Text(title), content: Text(message), actions: const []);

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: @ShanakaMadusanka  nah :( we are switching to firebase